# How do ampersand attributes know when to re-evaluate?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Take a look at this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bcaudan/SbrKj/

The key point is that there's some code like this on an isolate scope:

```
{attr1: "=", attr2: "&"}
```

--and when a change to attr1 changes the bound parent value, somehow attr2 automatically re-evaluates the express therein as well, which is a function that returns the value of attr1, and I have no idea how it knows that it needs to do that.

Comment: Angular knows it needs to evaluate all the `{{ }}` expressions in the template on each `$digest` cycle. The function didn't change, so Angular called the same function each time.

Comment: So the function is being called constantly to see if it's value has changed????????? That **can't** be efficient

Comment: No, it's only called on a digest, which only happens when a call to `$scope.$apply` is made. This happens inside the `ngModel` directive.

Comment: So you really need to be careful that these functions that trigger on $digest cycles aren't too heavy or you could incur some heavy performance penalties.

Comment: @Aerovistae you are correct re: functions that are interpolated. You shouldnt do any potentially blocking computations in them. Note. That digest cycle happens fairly often as a result of 'any' interaction with the page.

Comment: @Aerovistae `ngModel` binds data between an HTML element and a JS controller that is loaded when your page loads.  So, yes, it updates the DOM frequently, but it doesn't require a round trip back to the server to do so.  The reduction in server traffic makes 2-way binding a more efficient way to build a website.  The update is almost instantaneous, and the result is a faster, more responsive website.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely clear on what youre asking, but your directive's template is interpolating your `attr2`(or `delegateDisplay` in this case):

```
'{{delegateDisplay()}}<br>'
```

which naturally causes re-evaluation of `$scope.displayTitle()` function

Answer (score 0):

That is AngularJS doing 2-way binding.  You use the `ng-model` directive to bind a model variable to the HTML element.

You have a two way data binding when a model variable is bound to a HTML element that can both change and display the value of the variable. You could have more than one HTML element bound to the same variable.